# Method to create a cube in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, methods

How should the x, y, z, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ values be put to the vertices to make a cube?

```
public static void cube(float x, float y, float z, float sx, float sy, float sz){       
glPushMatrix();
    {
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);

//Just one side of the cube is given due to too much unnecessary code.
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1); 
            glVertex3f(1, -1, 1);
            glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
            glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
        glEnd();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever in your code you have e.g. `glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);` mulitply them with the corresponding value of sx, sy, sz divided by 2 e.g. `glVertex3f(-sx/2, -sy/2, sz/2);`

For the position you can issue a `glTranslatef(x, y, z)` before drawing the cube. If you insist on hardcoding this into the vertices then you should write the above statement as `glVertex3f(x - sx/2, y - sy/2, z + sz/2);`